# How to extract types from the values of another interface

Tags: typescript

Lets say i have an interface `TableHeader`:

```js
interface TableHeader{
  key: string,
  value: string,
}
```

later, i want to have interface of `TableData`, where:

```js
interface TableData{
  // ????
}
```

i want this table data `key` is the type of either one of `key` of `TableHeader[]`,

so for example if i type

```js
const tableHeaders : tableHeader[]=[
 { key: 'index', value: 'Index'},
 { key: 'firstName', value: 'First Name'},
 { key: 'lastName', value: 'Last Name'}
]
```

later, when i write

```
const tableData: TableData[] = [
  {
   // each of this object must contain keys `index`, `firstName`, `lastName` with 
   // their value, for example, can be string.
  },
  {
    .
    .
    .
  },
]
```

how do i achieve that?

Comment: Is `tableHeaders` really hardcoded in the code? If so, why not just define an interface for the type with `key`, `firstName`, and `lastName`? If not, if it's runtime data, I very much doublt you can do this.

Comment: Yeah, it seems impossible at runtime - how are you even going to define an **interface** at runtime - it's compiled to JS

Comment: no, i wanted the `tableHeaders` typed by the user dynamically, then the keys in `tableData` will follow of what the user typed.

Comment: You can mark it as `any` then. It doesn't matter in the compiled app, it's dynamically typed

Comment: my purpose is the typing capability of ts, so it will tell user they typed different keys in their `tableData` compared to what they type in their `tableHeaders`

Comment: You can use `typeof` keyword then

Comment: @casachii can you give some example please in the answer? it seems vague to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231752/discussion-between-casachii-and-hadi-kar).

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```js
// Table.ts

export interface Header<T>
{
    key: T;
    value: string;
}

export interface Data<T>
{
    key: T;
    value: string;
}

export class Table<T>
{

    headers: Header<T>[];
    data: Data<T>[];
    keys: T[];

    constructor()
    {
        this.headers = [];
        this.data = [];
        this.keys = [];
    }

    addHeader(...newHeader: Header<T>[]): void
    {
        this.headers.push(...newHeader);
        for (let i = 0; i < newHeader.length; i++)
            this.keys.push(newHeader[i].key);
    }

    addData(newData: Data<T>): void
    {
        if (this.keys.includes(newData.key))
        {
            this.data.push(newData);
        }
        else
        {
            throw "Data key not found in input array";
        }
    }

}

// Usecase.ts

import { Table } from './Table.js';

type keys = "index" | "firstName" | "lastName";
let table = new Table<keys>();

table.addHeader(
    {
        key: "index",
        value: "No."
    }
);

try
{
    table.addData({
        key: "index",
        value: "126037"
    });
} catch(error) {
    console.log(`Error: ${error}\n`);
}

console.log(table);
```